# Hibernate Pagination not working as expected

Tags: java, hibernate, pagination

I've been working on Hibernate for sometime now and recently ran into a strange problem while performing pagination using hibernate query.

I've a table which has two columns leaseNum, RegistraionDate

There are 12 records in the table where leaseNum column has unique values and RegistrationDate column has same date value.

I set the Query to fetch first 10 results as part of page 1 by ordering on column RegistraionDate desc.

I get 12 results and it carves out 10 results for me and as part of page I get 2 results but I get the same results which I got in Page 1 since the RegistrationDate column has same value.

Apologies, I dint complete details earlier, below is the illustration of the scenarios I'm trying to refer.

```
tmpQuery : "select * from CAMS_LEASE_DETAIL mylease0_ 
            order by mylease0_.LEASE_REG_DATE desc"
```

---

```
LeaseNum        RegDate
01.70837.012    24-02-2020 12:02:00
01.70837.011    07-02-2020 12:02:00
01.70837.010    04-02-2020 12:02:00
01.70837.004    17-01-2020 12:01:00
01.70837.005    17-01-2020 12:01:00
01.70837.007    17-01-2020 12:01:00
01.70837.008    17-01-2020 12:01:00
01.70837.009    17-01-2020 12:01:00
01.70837.003    17-01-2020 12:01:00
01.70837.002    17-01-2020 12:01:00
01.70837.001    17-01-2020 12:01:00
01.70837.006    17-01-2020 12:01:00
```

---

```
tmpQuery : "select * from CAMS_LEASE_DETAIL mylease0_ 
            order by mylease0_.LEASE_REG_DATE desc"
```

Page 1 :

```
    Query query = session.createQuery(tmpQuery);
    query.setFirstResult(0);
    query.setMaxResults(10);
```

Backend Query

```
select * from 
    ( select  mylease0_.LEASE_NUMBER as LEASE_NUMBER18_2_, 
              mylease0_.LEASE_REG_DATE as LEASE_REG_DATE19_2_ 
    from CAMS_LEASE_DETAIL mylease0_ 
    where mylease0_.ADDRESS_NUMBER='18201' 
    order by mylease0_.LEASE_REG_DATE desc ) 
where rownum <= 10;
```

ResultSet Retrieved is

```
01.70837.012    24-FEB-20
01.70837.011    07-FEB-20
01.70837.010    04-FEB-20
01.70837.001    17-JAN-20
01.70837.004    17-JAN-20
01.70837.005    17-JAN-20
01.70837.006    17-JAN-20
01.70837.007    17-JAN-20
01.70837.008    17-JAN-20
01.70837.009    17-JAN-20
```

Page 2 :

```
    Query query = session.createQuery(tmpQuery);
    query.setFirstResult(10);
    query.setMaxResults(20);
```

Backend Query

```
select * from 
    ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from 
        ( select mylease0_.LEASE_NUMBER as LEASE_NUMBER18_2_,
                mylease0_.LEASE_REG_DATE as LEASE_REG_DATE19_2_ 
         from CAMS_LEASE_DETAIL mylease0_ 
         where mylease0_.ADDRESS_NUMBER='18201' o
         rder by mylease0_.LEASE_REG_DATE desc ) 
     row_ where rownum <= 20) 
 where rownum_ > 10
```

ResultSet Retrieved is

```
01.70837.008    17-JAN-20
01.70837.009    17-JAN-20
```

Instead of getting of getting leases 01.70837.002, 01.70837.003

What should I do to avoid this issue.

Any help here would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because you're not showing the query but if you're not including an `order by` clause, then the order of the rows returned by the database is undetermined.

So your query should look like:

```
from Lease l order by l.leaseNum
```

As most of the dates seem to be 17-01-2020 12:01:00 there's no guaranteed row order when only sorting by that column. You should be able to solve that problem by adding a second column to your order clause:

```
from Lease l order by l.registrationDate, l.leaseNum
```